# Wrapper for ViewState on Service Layer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, modelstate

I have service layer objects that look like this one:

```
public class UserRepository
{

    [Inject]
    public IUnitOfWork Database { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    public IUserContext User { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    public IModelValidator ModelValidator { get; set; }

    public Response CreateUser(UserDTO dto) {
        if (ModelValidator.IsValid()) 
            return new Response {SuccessCode = -1, Message = "Please check all properties"};

        //Code to create the user goes here
    }

    public class Response {
        public int SuccessCode {get; set;}
        public string Message {get; set;}
    }
}
```

I wish to perform validation on my service layer, so that the whole business logic runs independently from the MVC implementation.

I wish to inject an MvcModelStateValidationWrapper using DI, but haven't found a way to access the `ModelStateDictionary` commonly available on any Controller.

Is there a way to create a wrapper and instantiate on a per-request basis?

What I want to ultimately achieve is to perform a mock validation on my unit tests.